# SQL query against a web page(or, advanced find)

Tags: sql, html, find

Suppose I have [a table](http://www.eia.doe.gov/emeu/aer/txt/ptb0808.html). Now, I'm interested in Getting Useful Data Easily. This means I'd rather not drop it into Excel and go through contortions, nor somehow get it into CSV and then into a DB, and then into SQL.

I'd like to be able to execute a SQL query directly against a table in HTML.

Has anyone heard of a tool like this before? I've never seen one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tool to query an HTML table with SQL as far as I know, but [XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/) is a standard language you can use to find elements in an XML or XHTML source in a manner very similar to using SQL to query databases.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is absolutely no tool that lets you run SQL queries against an HTML table... but you could easily write some simple JavaScript if you had a specific query you wanted done.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't *want* specific queries. ;) I want to be able to execute (reasonably) arbitrary SQL queries against HTML.